# how to mark LVM raid1 PV as in-sync

Tags: lvm, raid1

I am recovering from bad sectors on both sides of my LVM raid setup.
(It's the backup server, dammit).  I have new disks and a new install.
I could wipe the backup partition and suck 1TB of data across a slow link, and maybe I'll be forced to do that.  One of the failed drives is mostly salvageable to read/pvmove stuff off, but the other drive has many read errors and auto-allocation failures, and is not coming back as far as LVM is concerned.
(sdb3 is the half-assed, failed drive. sdd is the totally broken drive. sda, sdc are new drives)

```
istari# lvs --all -o +devices | grep TapeDisks
  TapeDisks                  istari rwi---r--- 800.00g                                                     TapeDisks_rimage_0(0),TapeDisks_rimage_1(0)            
  [TapeDisks_rimage_0]       istari Iwi---r--- 800.00g                                                     /dev/sdb3(10731)                                       
  [TapeDisks_rimage_0]       istari Iwi---r--- 800.00g                                                     /dev/sdb3(100333)                                      
  [TapeDisks_rimage_0]       istari Iwi---r--- 800.00g                                                     /dev/sdb3(264174)                                      
  [TapeDisks_rimage_1]       istari vwi---r--- 800.00g                                                                                                            
  [TapeDisks_rmeta_0]        istari ewi---r---   4.00m                                                     /dev/sdb3(5963)                                        
  [TapeDisks_rmeta_1]        istari ewi---r---   4.00m
```

The capital I means that the "mirror or raid (I)mage out-of-sync", and perhaps this means that the file system is catastrophically broken.  Or maybe fsck can fix it and save some significant data transfer.  I can get it all from off-site, but this annoys me, so I'm asking.

I have tried:

```
istari# lvchange -ay --force /dev/istari/TapeDisks                 
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (253:32) failed: Invalid argument
```

and dmesg says:

```
[ 1303.485131] device-mapper: raid: Failed to read superblock of device at position 1
[ 1303.494755] md: pers->run() failed ...
[ 1303.494835] device-mapper: table: 253:32: raid: Failed to run raid array
[ 1303.494895] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
```

```
lvconvert --force --type linear /dev/istari/TapeDisks
```

I read that I could grab the data off of /dev/sdb3 with the right offsets, as I also have the /etc/lvm from the broken disk in a safe place.

Comment: `fsck` won't fix your data, it may only fix an inconsistent file system, by deleting/moving the inconsistent parts of it, your data. If you don't know what you are doing, better do nothing and ask professionals for help. You should stop trying to "repair" as you lack the skills needed for doing so.